# ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet intermittently takes too long to route requests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a legacy rails app where intermittently some request take too long to be routed to the correct action.We using rails 3.0.10

**Rack Timer (Application Action) -- ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet: 20506.478548049927 ms**

Is there any place I can start debugging to figure out more?

Answer (score 0):

I had been wondering about it for some time now. I have been tracing middleware times on Graphite and could see a stark similarity between the total application runtime and the runtime for `ActionDispatch::RailsRouting::Routset`. The graphs have almost been overlapping.

Found a possible explanation in one of the posts made by Luke Ludwig (the guy who wrote Rack Timer).

> It will also print out the time elapsed by the actual application's action, which is combined with Rails routing, the final piece of middleware.

Source: http://pulse.sportngin.com/news_article/show/137153?referrer_id=543230

Turns out that Rails routing includes the total time spent by the application, hence a high runtime.

Hope this helps!