# Why would I see ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call slowness?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, heroku

Looking at my New Relic data for my Heroku app, there's one transaction that's puzzling me.  It's the only one where ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call appears in the trace.  It takes up about 30% of the time on a very frequent action, so I'd like to speed it up, or at least understand what it does.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/kvs5ez7stxpul1n/Screenshot%202015-07-16%2011.00.17.png?dl=0

Also weird is that every now and then, it takes a REALLY long time:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/636lrmny3mu20o4/Screenshot%202015-07-16%2011.03.57.png?dl=0

I've asked myself, "What is different about this particular request?"  The controller action is pretty normal -- and the fact that the slow-down is in Middleware makes me think that the controller code isn't relevant.  (Can someone confirm that?)  The only thing that I can think of is that this particular action uses non-integer resource IDs: e.g /action_name/some-id-with-dashes.  It's the only action in my app that does this.  Is it possible that this can be the cause?  What does ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call do anyway?  Are there any theories that someone can give me to point me in a fruitful direction?

I'll sum that all up in a single question: **What could be different about a single rails action such that one would see slowness with ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call in its trace?**

PRIOR RESEARCH

I found other (unanswered) SO questions on the topic.  But I decided to open a separate question because some of the details differed in my case.  Listing them here:

1) Similar, but ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call is listed in New Relic as a transaction, whereas for me it is a segment within a transaction:

[ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call Rails 4.1 really slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28351527/actiondispatchroutingroutesetcall-rails-4-1-really-slow)

2) Similar, but involves Rails 4 and also the slowdown they are experiencing is way larger than mine and seems to be "memory related", whereas my app's memory use seems fine:

[Slow action in Rails application: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28430614/slow-action-in-rails-application-actiondispatchroutingroutesetcall)

3) Similar, but I don't know what "Grape" is (and I'm not using it):

[Why ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet takes so long](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30128883/why-actiondispatchroutingrouteset-takes-so-long)

4) Might be the same issue, but there aren't a lot of details, just that ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#call is sometimes slow:

[ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet intermittently takes too long to route requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10690148/actiondispatchroutingrouteset-intermittently-takes-too-long-to-route-request)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? We are facing the same problem

Comment: We have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For me, it turns out that Newrelic ruby agent does't work with rocket_pants, the gem I use to build API endpoints.

There is a third party gem 'rocket_pants-rpm' to solve this issue, but the original one stop working from newrelic_rpm version 3.9+, to fix the issue, try using the forked version at https://github.com/SpartaSales/rocket_pants-rpm

This is how newrelic report looks for me after adding this gem.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVRvj.png)